# Is it possible for a custom view to be implemented in another application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following in my application (`com.para.app1`):

```
    <com.para.app2.MyKeyboardView
        ...
```

which is a custom view. The implementing class (I.e. `MyKeyboardView`) is defined in another application (com.para.app2) which is already installed on my device.

Although I have used a fully qualified class name in my `layout.xml (that's "com.para.app2.MyKeyboardView")`, every time I run my app, I face `ClassNotFoundException` for `MyKeyboardView`.

Any idea?

Comment: this is because each process has its own indenpendent VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know about the error, the issue is that your applications are running in their own processes and VM instance.

Now to answer your question, It is possible, but it would be a dumb idea to take the time to do so since it might have an important impact in performance, either way you might be able to accomplish it by making both apps share the same process(which is possible if both apps are signed with the same key only)but I would strongly recommend you to have the class in both applications and avoid all that useless overload on your apps.

Anyway if both apps are using same process you can use Context.createPackageContext() to instantiate a package for the other app as long as both apps are using the same shared user ID, then you can get the ClassLoader from the context and instantiate whatever classes you want.

Regards!

Comment: How can I use my custom class loader in an android application? I mean, where is the best place to set a custom loader for an android application?

Comment: Well that's up to you, the only thing you need to be really aware of is that it should be implemented in a way where you check that the other app is installed and handle gracefully if is not, and retry later to see if can find it again

Comment: For test purpose, I write: contxt = createPackageContext("com.parasum.delikey", 0); cls = contxt.getClassLoader(); cls.loadClass("com.parasum.delikey.MyGestureOverlayView"); BUT IT ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS, UNDER ANY CONDITION, THROWS "CLASS NOT FOUND" :-(

Comment: You must sign both apps with same key, use same user Id and configure both manifest to run under the same process

Comment: Both apps has been built in eclipse in DEBUG mode, so I thought they were both signed with the same signature. Am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed they are both signed with same key, now make sure to configure the manifest to run both apps on same process

Answer (score -1):

No.  You must have all the classes your app uses in your apk.  The only way to run code in another apk is via an Intent.  Of course you can't use an Intent to make a view.